# Action to crop a photo with user input. The batch processing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I'm stumped.  All I need to do is open my photo, have the action stop to wait for me to decide where the crop should be (to center the important part of the photo), then close that photo so the batch processing can go get the next photo.  I see the "inset stop" is the key, but it never allows me to crop, it just moves on to the next photo.

Comment: Hey LBVandal and welcome. Could you include the script that you're working with?

Comment: Entire action is simply "crop" as the batch processing will open, save and close it.   I just need to zoom in on the part of the photo I need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common misunderstanding with actions.

`Insert Stop` can be used to give kind of like a reminder **or** to give a full stop. Full stop in the sense that it can stop the Action there and you have to manually continue the Action when you're done with what ever you need to do in between.

In the `Insert stop` window, checking `Allow continue` basically makes it a message that shows up and can continue normally after that. Unchecking it makes it a full stop.

I might use it if I need to remember that this action should only be used with print images or something. The other use case for me is debugging the Action. If the Action doesn't do something correctly, just put a stop where you think it might be going south and see what happens. Easier than disabling Action items one by one.

---

**If you want user interaction with a specific item in the Action, you gotta click the empty box on the left side of it.** If you enable dialogs, the action will wait until you Crop and then continue once you apply it.

[image]